# Does a C# project contain any record of original extensions for Properties.Resources files?

Tags: c#

From what I understand, once [a file is added to Properties.Resources in the following manner](https://ikriv.com/blog/?p=1530), it does not retain any record of its original extension:

> When you edit project resources on the Resources tab of the project property pages, Visual Studio creates another special resx file named Properties\Resources.resx. Corresponding manifest resource name is ProjectName.Properties.Resources.resources (yes, “resources” is repeated twice, one comes from the file name, and the other from the “.resx” extension being replaced with “.resources”). Visual Studio also creates a file called Resources.Designer.cs that contains code for easy access to the dictionary items.

This matches what I'm seeing in both the Resources tab of the project properties, and in the `DictionaryEntry`s (resource variable) obtained with the following code:

```
        var resourceSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        foreach(var resource in resourceSet)
        {
        }
```

One example resource resolves to:

> {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}
>   
>      Key: "(Filename without extension)"
>   
>      Value: {byte[221773]}
>   
>      _key: "(Filename without extension)"
>   
>      _value: {byte[221773]}

I'm trying to figure out if there's a record of the original file extensions so I can use a generic method to write these files with their original extensions. For example, I'd like to be able to know if a file originally had an .xlsx extension, so I can write it to disk via WriteAllBytes with .xlsx extension and then open it with an instance of Excel:

```
    public static void WriteResourcesFileToTemporaryProgramFiles(dynamic resourcesFile)
    {
        var tempDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(new string[] { Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "EDI File Utilities"});
        if (!Directory.Exists(tempDirectoryPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectoryPath);
        }

        string tempFilePath;
        var originalExtension = (however I would get the original extension of the resourcesFile here);

        switch (resourcesFile.GetType().ToString())
        {
            case "System.Byte[]":
                tempFilePath = Path.Combine(new string[] { tempDirectoryPath, nameof(resourcesFile) + originalExtension });
                File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, resourcesFile);
                break;
            case "System.String":
                tempFilePath = Path.Combine(new string[] { tempDirectoryPath, nameof(resourcesFile) + originalExtension });
                File.WriteAllText(tempFilePath, resourcesFile);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Extensions are fairy meaningless - they just give us a way to assign a default program. When you compile a file into your resources like that you’re just storing a blob of data - the extension is meaningless. Given that you should know what’s in your resource pack when compiling the program, what does this really gain you? You could include the extension in the resource name and use nameof to parse it out if you’re he’ll bent on doing it this way.

Comment: @MichaelJones If you can confirm that no record is kept of the original file extension for resource files, please feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: It doesn’t. Once you embed it into your app it just becomes part of the binary. It isn’t a file at that point, it’s just a byte array. Nothing else is stored.